# How to get the selected dropdown list in edit modal with Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

i am building a project with laravel where i am able to fetch the record from database into my modal but the problem is everytime do i update my modal then the options values in both the select also gets incremented with the same fetched result. How to avoid that. Here i am pasting two images before and after of edit and also what i have done till now. Please help me to complete it.

Before Image

[image]

After Image

[image]

My modal part

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-href="{{ url('admin/product_edit/'.$cat->id) }}" class="edit_product btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal"> Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title font-weight-bold" id="insertModalLabel">EditCustomer</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p><b>Please note:</b> Fields marked with <span class="control-label"></span> is mandatory</p>
                          <form action="{{ url('admin/update_product') }}" method="post" class="edit_database_operation">
                            @csrf
                            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="eid" id="eid">
                            {{-- <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="brand_id" id="brand_id">
                            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id"> --}}
                            
                            <div class="form-row">
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="eproduct_category" class="control-label">Product Category</label>
                                <select id="eproduct_category" class="form-control" name="eproduct_category">
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="eproduct_brand" class="control-label">Product Brand</label>
                                <select id="eproduct_brand" class="form-control" name="eproduct_brand">
                                </select>
                              </div>
                            </div>     
                            
                                              

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-left">Submit</button>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

The script part

```
$(document).on('click','.edit_product',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        success:function(fb){
            var resp = $.parseJSON(fb);
            console.log(resp);
            $('#eid').val(resp.id);
            var brand_id = resp.brand_id;
            brand_edit(brand_id);
            var category_id = resp.category_id;
            category_edit(category_id);
        }

    });
    return false;
});

function brand_edit(brand_id){
    url = '/admin/edit_product_brand/'+brand_id;
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        success:function(fb){
            console.log(fb);
            $('#eproduct_brand').append(fb);
        }
    });
    return false;

}

function category_edit(category_id){
    url = '/admin/edit_product_category/'+category_id;
    console.log(url);
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"GET",
        success:function(fb){
            console.log(fb);
            $('#eproduct_category').append(fb);
        }
    });
    return false;

}

$(document).on('submit','.edit_database_operation',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method:"POST",
        data:data,
        success:function(fb){
            var resp = $.parseJSON(fb);
            // console.log(resp);
            if(resp.status=='true'){
                toastr.success(resp.message,'Success');
                $('#editModal').modal('hide');
                $('.edit_database_operation')[0].reset();
                $("#example1").load(" #example1 > *");
                $("#example2").load(" #example2 > *");
                // $('.edit_database_operation')[0].reset();
                $("#eproduct_category").data("default-value",$("#eproduct_category").val());
            }else if(resp.status=='false'){
                    
                $.each( resp.message, function( key , value ) {
                toastr.error(value + '<br>','Error');
                });
                

            }else if(resp.status=='false-1'){
                toastr.error(resp.message,'Error');
            }

            
            
            
        }

    });
    
    return false;
});
```

The Controller part

```
public function product_edit($id){
        $edit = Product::where('id',$id)->first();
        $arr = array('id'=>$edit->id,'category_id'=>$edit->category_id,'brand_id'=>$edit->brand_id);
        echo json_encode($arr);
    }
    
    public function edit_product_brand($id){
        $brande = Brand::where('status','active')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $output = '';
        // $output .= '';
        foreach ($brande as $brand){
        $brand_id = $brand->id;
        $brand_name = $brand->brand_name;

        $output .= '<option value="'.$brand_id.'" '.(($brand_id == $id) ? 'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$brand_name.'</option>';

        }
        // $output .='</select>';

        return $output;
    }

    public function edit_product_category($id){
        $category = Category::where('status','active')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $output = '';
        if(!$category->isEmpty()){
            
            foreach ($category as $brand){
                $category_id = $brand->id;
                $category_name = $brand->category_name;
        
                $output .= '<option value="'.$category_id.'" '.(($category_id == $id) ? 'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$category_name.'</option>';
        
            }
            
        }

        return $output;
    }


    public function update_product(Request $request){

        $update = Product::where('id',$request->eid)->first();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
        [
            
            'eproduct_category'=>'required',
            'eproduct_brand'=>'required',
        ],[
            
            'eproduct_category.required'=>'Please enter product category',
            'eproduct_brand.required'=>'Please enter product brand',
            
        ]);
        if(!$validator->fails()){
            
                    $update->name = $request->eproduct_name;
                    $update->category_id = $request->eproduct_category;
                    $update->brand_id = $request->eproduct_brand;
                    if($update->update()){
                        $arr = array('status'=>'true','message'=>'Updated Successfully');
                    }else{
                        $arr = array('status'=>'false-1','message'=>'Not Updated');
                    }
        }else{
            $arr = array('status'=>'false','message'=>$validator->errors()->all());
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);

    }
```

Comment: you have empty before for loop

Comment: I have removed that but still the same result

Comment: Hi you have use `append` here so result which is return by your ajax just append from the option which is already there inside `select-box`.Instead use  `.html(fb)` it will remove any previous data and add new data .

Comment: @Swati Okay i am trying

Comment: Thanks correct!!! @Swati please give that in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery code you have use [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) to append new options inside your select-box which just insert new elements to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.So that's the reason it was showing double values.

Instead use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace all element which are there inside your select-box. So you just need to change :

```
 $('#eproduct_brand').append(fb);
```

To

```
$('#eproduct_brand').html(fb);
```

Same you do for `eproduct_category` as well.